# What is the impact of CSS Validation Failure?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am developing a asp.net website. When I used the CSS property "word-wrap", VIsual Studio 2010 is showing a warning: Validation (CSS 2.1) 'word-wrap' is not a known CSS property name.

When I tested the website, it is working fine. However, can there be any issue in using this property ignoring the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that is proprietary will only work in the browser that it is for. In other browsers, it is simply ignored. So in some way it is safe to ignore the warning, as long as you know it will not break the layout of the page in browsers that do not support the feature.

As far as the feature itself, from what I checked, it is a CSS3 feature. Which is why it will not validate as CSS2.1:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923936/how-to-use-the-word-wrap-property-in-css-2-1-and-validate-css

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap

Answer (score 4):

You may ignore css warnings as far as they do not break your page layout.
However, if you do not use HTML validation in your development, you may turn off it as well.

You'll need to turn off HTML Validation:

- **Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Validation**
- Uncheck the "Show Errors" check box.

And CSS file error detection:

- **Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS > CSS Specific**
- Uncheck "Detect Errors"